# Wordpress apply_filters for subclasses

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

I'm writing a plugin and while adding the hooks, I'm discovering that I'm going to have to write the *same* filters over and over, for each subclass. So if B, C, and D are children of A I have to make a filter with keys for 'b_dosomething', 'c_something', and 'd_something' in order to allow the children to do accept this filter.

Is there a way to do this more generically? but just adding 'dosomething' and passing something to that.. maybe?

Answer (score 0):

make a function in class A

```
class A {

  public function __construct()
   {
       $this->apply_filters();
    }


   public function apply_filters()
   {
     if(!method_exists($this, 'filter_callback'))
        return;
     apply_filter('your_filter_here', array($this,'filter_callback'));
   }
}
```

Now the child classes, if you have function 'filter_callback', then the filter will be applied.

```
class B extends A{

   public function __construct()
   {
      parent::__construct;
    }

    public function filter_callback()
    {
       //do something
     }
}
```

This way, you do not have to take overhead of calling appply_filter() repeatadely.

Hope this answers your Question

Comment: But when I use add_filter, how will wp know that i only want that filter to apply to A objects?

Comment: suppose you made object of B in your plugin, then on class construction, A's __construct is called which calls `$this->apply_filter()` function inside class A. If you notice, A calls this function by default whenever you extend A. But the filter is only called if you have defined `filter_callback()` in child class.

Comment: I understand. Let's say I have a post type parent class, and a bunch of children. I have the apply_filter in the parent as you're suggesting, but if there is a filter that modifies some aspect of the post type, it has to apply to all children, but I dont want to make 1 generic add_filter, I need to be able to add_filter for each child to filter the same attribute, but differently for each child.

Comment: If i am not mistaken what actually is your goal, please see this [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/66m-8u7). Things might be litle clear. you can update with your code there.:)